# Blue shirt guy on an airship

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching this show back in the 2000s where a guy with a blue shirt with curly mustaches moving around in a huge airship. He was very energetic and probably became stronger after eating an apple. I don't remember, but he did like apples a lot. What show was it?

Comment: Was it animated or live-action?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounds like you were watching [*Lazy Town.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LazyTown)  The "blue shirt guy with curly mustaches on an airship" would be [Sportacus.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sportacus)

From the Wikipedia article:

[image]

*Lazy Town* was a children's show that was all about being healthy and fit.  Sportacus was always helping the folks in Lazy Town fight against Robbie Rotten, who is always trying to get the people of Lazy Town to be lazy.

I didn't watch many episodes with my kids, but I'm pretty sure Sportacus would have eaten apples.

Wikipedia says:

> Sportacus lives on a diet of fruit and vegetables, which he refers to as "sports candy".

He lives in an airship that flies around above Lazy Town.

The show was made with a mixture of live action, puppets, and special effects.

Comment: It's a piece of cake to bake a pretty cake!